# Aligning Text to the Right Hand Side of an Image Sencha Touch CSS

Tags: css, sencha-touch

I have the following item template:

```
itemTpl:'<img src="{ThumbnailImage}"></img> <h1>{Name}</h1>',
            itemCls:'vegetable-entry'
```

which uses the `vegetable-entry` class.

The vegetable entry class is defined as follows:

```
.vegetable-entry img 
{
    height:60px;
    weight:60px;
    float:left;
}

.vegetable-entry h1 
{
    float:left;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

It is not really aligning properly! What am I missing?

HERE is the image:

[image]

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean by "It is not really aligning properly!" Can you support this statement with anything that would make the problem more clear?

Comment: I added an image to give you a better idea of the output/result.

Comment: It looks like it is aligning to the right, but you need to clear the `float` after each element, or they will just compound with each other.

Comment: You want each vegetal (image and text) in unique lines or side by side? Try to add an image with the ideal output

Comment: What do you mean unique lines? I just want each vegetable along with the text on the same line for each row.